how to create a disabled state for next button when at the end of the carousel?
I'm trying to add a disabled state to my custom button group, specifically the next button. The previous button uses the currentSlide method which returns a number .. so you  can write
currentSlide === 0 ? 'disabled' : 'not disabled'

Is there a way i can do this when you are at the end of the carousel ?
I haven't found anything that works for this yet but looking for suggestions.

here is the documentation https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-multi-carousel
